# Image is not displaying after uploading it through client and retrieving it from API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, mongoose, multer

I'm currently building a React JS app that communicates with an API that I am also building with Node JS at the same time, and I am stuck on the problem of getting an image to be uploaded and be displayed correctly. I surmised that the problem originates from how the app handles uploading the image.

The user uploads a profile picture through the following form:

```
            <form
                id="RegistrationForm"
                ref={FormRef}
                encType="multipart/form-data"
                className={`bg-[#f2e798] w-11/12 md:w-9/12 mx-auto lg:w-6/12 mt-[20px] py-10 rounded box_shadow`}
                onSubmit={(evt) => {
                    evt.preventDefault(); 
                    const ImageInputElem = ImageInputRef.current; 
                    UploadNewProfilePic(uploadURL, ImageInputElem, setPictureError)
                }}
            >
                <div className= "FormStyle w-11/12 mx-auto grid">
                    <label htmlFor="profile_pic">Profile picture</label>
                    <input
                        name="profile_pic"
                        id="profile_picInput"
                        ref={ImageInputRef}
                        type="file"
                        placeholder="Upload an image htmlFor your your profile picture here"
                        className="text-lg file:rounded-lg file:font-['DecoTech'] file:bg-[#99cbae] file:text-white cursor-pointer border-black border-[1px] rounded"
                        onChange={(evt) => { HandleFileChange(evt, setImage) }}
                    />
                    <FormButtons />
                </div>
                <div
                    id="pictureError"
                    className="ErrorDiv"
                    ref={ImageErrorRef}>
                    {pictureError != null && pictureError.length > 0 && RenderError(pictureError)}
                </div>
        </form>
```

The following hook is used to send the fetch request to the server when the user submits the form:

```
    const UploadNewProfilePic = async (apiURL, ImageInputElem, setPictureError) => {
        const formData = new FormData; 
        formData.append("profile_pic", ImageInputElem.files[0])
        try {
            await fetch(apiURL,
                {
                    method: "PUT",
                    body: formData,
                }
            )
                .then(async response => {
                    const result = await response.json();

                    if (response.ok) {
                        console.log("Uploaded image successfully: ", result.message)
                        GoHome();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Upload failed: ", result.error)
                        RenderErrorArray(result.error, setPictureError);
                    }
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error uploading file:", error);
            RenderErrorArray([{ para: "file upload error", msg: `Upload error: ${error}` }], setPictureError);
        }
    }
```

On the server side, the route is set up as the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); 
const cors = require('cors'); 
const UserController = require('../controller/userController.js'); 
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "public/uploads")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        const filename = `${Date.now()}-${file.filename}${ext}`;
        cb(null, filename)
    },
});


const upload = multer({
    limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 },
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
            return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'));
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
}); 



router.put('/users/:id/uploadnewpicture', cors(), upload.single("profile_pic"), UserController.UploadNewProfilePicture)
```

The type of the uploaded image to be stored is of type buffer:

```
const User = new Schema({
    //...
    profile_pic: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
     //...

})
```

The following controller function is used to handle the PUT request:

```
exports.UploadNewProfilePicture = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { BufferImage } = dataHooks();          
        const BufferedImg = {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../public/uploads/', req.file.filename)),
            contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        }
        const updates = {
            _id: req.params.id,
            profile_pic: BufferedImg, 
        }
        const updateUser = new User(updates)
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, updateUser)
            .then(() => {
                return res.status(200).json({message: "Profile picture has been successfully updates."})
            })
            .catch(e => {
                return res.status(404).json({ error: [{ param: "server", msg: `Error in updating profile picture: ${e}.` }] })
            })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error in uploading new profile picture: ", e)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: [{para: "server error", msg: `Upload error: ${e}`}]})
    } 
}
```

Then, back to the client side, when the app renders a page that renders the profile image, it executes the following hook to retrieve the image from the server:

```
    const FetchProfilePic = async (apiURL, userID, dispatch) => {
        await fetch(apiURL,
            {
                method: "GET",
            }
        )
            .then(async response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    await response.json()
                        .then(result => {
                            localStorage.setItem("ProfilePicture", JSON.stringify(result.profile_pic))
                            dispatch(result.profile_pic)
                        })
                }
                else {
                    const result = await response.json();
                    console.log("Error in fetching image: ", result.error)
                }
            })
    }
```

Finally, it utilizes the following hook to render the profile image:

```
const RenderProfilePic = props => {
    const { profile_pic } = props;
    const ImageStyle = `select-none w-[270px] h-[270px] object-cover rounded-full mx-auto`;
    const ImageWrapperStyle = `m-auto overflow-hidden relative z-[1]`; 
    console.log("profile_pic: ", typeof profile_pic.data)
    const binaryData = new Uint8Array(profile_pic.data);
    const base64Image = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, binaryData));

    //const base64Image = profile_pic.data.toString('base64');

    const dataURL = `data:${profile_pic.contentType};base64,${base64Image}`;
    try {
        return (
            <div
                id="ImageWrapper"
                className={ImageWrapperStyle}
            >
                <img src={dataURL} alt="Profile Picture" className={`${ImageStyle}`} />
            </div>
        )
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error in rendering image: ", e)
    }
}
```

What I notice is that whenever the image is retrieved by the client from the server, the type of image comes as an object instead of type buffer.

```
console.log(typeof profile_pic) // returns object
```

I would appreciate it if anyone here can give me some guidance on how to solve this problem.

[Github for client site](https://github.com/Albertyhu/BlogClient)

[Github for server site](https://github.com/Albertyhu/BlogAPI)

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally resolve the problem with the help of someone else.

The problem is that buffer data can't be interpreted outside of Node. So, it needs be converted to base64 first.

I implemented the following function:

```
    function toBase64(arr) {
        console.log("toBase64 arr: ", arr)
        return btoa(
            arr.reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
        );
    }
```

It triggers when the app receives the buffer data from the server and converts it to base64.